# Database/Schema is not being switched when API is called

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, multi-tenant

I am trying to implement hibernate multitenancy in my SpringBootWebApplication.

**PROBLEM - tenant is being set in filter but when query is called Datasource is not being switched.
bad SQL grammar []; nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "xyz" does not exist.**

Here are the details

- spring-boot-starter-parent -- 2.5.12
- MyBatis for BE queries.
- Hibernate for multi-tenancy.

```
    @Configuration
    @EnableTransactionManagement
    @EnableJpaRepositories(
        basePackages = {"com.xyz.*"}
    )
    public class HibernateConfig {
        @Autowired
        private JpaProperties jpaProperties;
    
        public HibernateConfig() {
        }
    
        @Bean
        JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter() {
            return new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        }
    
        @Bean(name = {"entityManagerFactory"})
        public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(DataSource dataSource, MultiTenantConnectionProvider multiTenantConnectionProviderImpl, CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver currentTenantIdentifierResolverImpl){
            Map<String, Object> jpaPropertiesMap = new HashMap(this.jpaProperties.getProperties());
            jpaPropertiesMap.put("hibernate.multiTenancy", MultiTenancyStrategy.SCHEMA);
            jpaPropertiesMap.put("hibernate.multi_tenant_connection_provider", multiTenantConnectionProviderImpl);
            jpaPropertiesMap.put("hibernate.tenant_identifier_resolver", currentTenantIdentifierResolverImpl);
            jpaPropertiesMap.put("hibernate.format_sql", true);
            jpaPropertiesMap.put("hibernate.show_sql", true);
            LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
            em.setDataSource(dataSource);
            em.setJpaVendorAdapter(this.jpaVendorAdapter());
            em.setJpaPropertyMap(jpaPropertiesMap);
            em.setPackagesToScan(new String[]{"com.xyz.*"});
            return em;
        }
    }
```

```
    @Component
    public class DataSourceBasedMultiTenantConnectionProviderImpl extends AbstractDataSourceBasedMultiTenantConnectionProviderImpl {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        private static final String DEFAULT_TENANT_ID = "master";
        @Autowired
        private DataSource defaultDS;
        @Autowired
        private ApplicationContext context;
        private Map<String, DataSource> map = new HashMap();
        boolean init = false;
    
        public DataSourceBasedMultiTenantConnectionProviderImpl() {
        }
    
        @PostConstruct
        public void load() {
            this.map.put("master", this.defaultDS);
        }
    
        protected DataSource selectAnyDataSource() {
            return (DataSource)this.map.get("master");
        }
    
        protected DataSource selectDataSource(String tenantIdentifier) {
            if (!this.init) {
                this.init = true;
                TenantDataSource tenantDataSource = (TenantDataSource)this.context.getBean(TenantDataSource.class);
                this.map.putAll(tenantDataSource.getAll());
            }
    
            return this.map.get(tenantIdentifier) != null ? (DataSource)this.map.get(tenantIdentifier) : (DataSource)this.map.get("master");
        }
    }
```

The above Datasource provider is not being called.
Thanks in advance for your Help!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the issue.

My project is using MyBatis for Database queries. Since the configuration is set via hibernate, so using SpringDataJPA or hibernate helped in switching the DB while triggering the query.